# Configuring an array of configuration objects using Constretto

Tags: java, configuration, frameworks

I'm considering using [Constretto](http://constretto.github.io/) for my current configuration needs, but I couldn't figure out from the manual/wiki how to configure an array or list of configuration objects (just single fields / methods).

The use case I'm referring to is something like having a list of servers, each one has an ip, port and some other data, and I want to get a list or array of the servers.

I might have just missed it, but I would appreciate it if someone could explain it or at least direct me to where it's explained.